# Confused about reaching objects created in another class

Tags: java, class, instance, getter

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 ReadAuthor ReadAuth = new ReadAuthor();
 ReadCommands readCom = new ReadCommands(); }
```

In ReadARticles class I have a method for creating **arraylist** of articles.

```
 public class ReadArticles {
 public ArrayList<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();

 while(i=0;i<line number;,++){
       public void readDaFile(){
           articleList.add( new Article(ID,name,publisherName,publishYear));
            }
```

From `ReadCommands` class , I call `ReadArt.readDaFile`(reads but also creates arraylist).

```
    public class ReadCommands {
    ReadArticles readArt = new ReadArticles();
       public void readDaFile(){
             readArt.tryOpeningOrDieTrying(filename);
             readArt.readDaFile(); }
```

My problem is ;from main ,I can reach `articlelist` by ;

```
 System.out.println(readCom.readArt.articleList.get(20).getPublisherName());
```

or

```
 System.out.println(readCom.getArticleList().size());
```

But I can not reach article list from `readAuthor` class(another class created for reading authors and creating arraylists for them.

I even tried creating `getter` for `ArticleList` in both `ReadCommands` and `ReadArticles` classes to make sure but `getters` work only for main. My aim is seeing articleList from ReadAuthor class.

Answer (score 0):

`ReadAuthor` and `ReadCommands` are probably not in the same package.

Make `ReadArticles readArt` `public` in `ReadCommands`

Since there is no access modifier specified the default is "Package Protected".

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).